# Unable to Distribute App to Testflight or App Store - options not available

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app that has been around for several years, though I have not distributed it myself in a couple years.

The app builds fine, and I am able to Archive the app fine.  Upon going into the Xcode Organizer, I am given the option to "Distribute Content" not "Distribute App".  When I click the Distribute Content button I get this:

[image]

I am not given any options to deploy to TestFlight or the App Store.  I have checked signing settings, and ensured they are correct.  I've even manually downloaed provisioning profiles.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to resolve this?

Comment: how long ago? each year, the specific requirements have changed.... over time you might be tripping over a requirement that makes the other forms of distribution inaccessible.

Comment: This means you are not building/archiving an actual iOS app. Make sure you are selecting and building/archiving an iOS app target.

Comment: @benc This app was built originally like 7 years ago and is React Native.  I think that is part of the issue, standards have changed a lot since then.

Comment: If you create a new project in Xcode 15, and then compare the contents of the project file, you can probably find what is missing. Or you could consider asking developer support to list the dependencies.